# Is readMetadata() the only way to retrieve complete Profile information?

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Is there any way other than using the Metadata API's readMetadata() method to retrieve the complete Profile detail (ProfileFlowAccess, etc) metadata?

Unlike PermissionSets, retrieve() Profile only returns User Permissions unless you include the related metadata types (eg, Flow) in the retrieve request.

I've tried SOQL and Tooling API with no success; presumably these fail for the same reason that a bare retrieve() fails.

Comment: Have you tried adding * Flows type in the retrieve call along with the profiles? That's usually how you can retrieve metadata specific information from Profile metadata.

Comment: @tugce Yes. I'm trying to avoid pulling data that I don't need. I've updated my question to be more specific.